# Chef - Housing large tarball files

Tags: git, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am currently getting into chef configuration management and trying to find the best way to house large tarball files to be pulled by nodes. For example, if I have a recipe that involves pushing a tarball to a node then extracting it, I am unsure of where to house these.

I was thinking keep them in git so I can grab them with a `wget` but the limit there is only 100mb. Would I house them all on my server then sftp them to the nodes?  Is there a common practice in Chef in doing this?

Comment: Consider using the ark cookbook to handle the download and extraction of archive packages. It think you'll find it useful https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pretty much anything to do that. If nodes only need to download from there, then simplest will be some nginx or apache site. You will need a place to store the files, e.g. `/var/www/mytars` and nginx or apache running on that machine with a site configured. Then any node can download with `remote_file` resource.

Comment: The one thing I will add is that storing them in S3 is usually just easier.

Comment: So you are saying host the apache on the chef server then pull from there?

Comment: You can host the apache on any machine, it does not have to be the one where Chef Server is installed.